# Strange word order

Tags: grammar

I've come across such a sentence: "Some of the historical events may have Nostradamus predicted were ...". Shouldn't it be "events Nostradamus may have predicted"? It's C1 text so probably it's correct. Could you tell the difference?

Comment: Looks like a tupo to me.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://newsworlddaily.wordpress.com/featured-articles/future-predictions-of-nostradamus-21st-century/) (which you should have provided yourself). (And BTW, Nostradamus is nonsense. If you look at the way the original text has been corrupted and mistranslated, you come away with literally nothing.)

Answer (score 4):

The text you cited does not make sense. You are right in saying it should read as follows: "some of the historical events Nostradamus may have predicted were..."

*Note: your suggested re-wording is technically correct, but it doesn't flow beautifully. If I were editing this sentence, I would suggest a complete re-write, like so:

- "Some examples of historical events that may have been predicted by Nostradamus are as follows;"

Comment: "The subject of the sentence should be Nostradamus": this is not correct. The subject of the sentence "some of the historical events Nostradamus may have predicted were..." is the noun phrase "some of the historical events Nostradamus may have predicted"; alternatively you may see the subject as "some" (the head of the noun phrase) with the prepositional phrase "of the historical events Nostradamus may have predicted" describing "some."

Comment: The object of "of" in that prepositional phrase is the noun phrase "the historical events Nostradamus may have predicted," the head of which is "events." The phrase "Nostradamus may have predicted" is a relative clause with the [zero relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Zero_relative_pronoun). That is, there's an implied "that" ("the historical events [that] Nostradamus may have predicted"). Thus, Nostradamus *is* the subject...of the relative clause describing "events," which is the object of "of," which describes the *sentence's* subject, "some."

Comment: Thanks, I will update my answer to remove the point about subject vs. object as this was not strictly relevant.

Comment: You can't necessarily re-write the sentence like that (and I wouldn't do it personally, even if it was possible -- your version doesn't "flow beautifully" for me, even ignoring that egregious semicolon). For instance, "Some of the historical events Nostradamus may have predicted were subsequently shown to be unsubstantiated."

Comment: I won't take lessons on semicolons from someone who writes "even if it was possible", but thanks for the personal opinion!